# Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_INCLUDE_DIR) (found suitable version "7.74.0", minimum required is "7.74.0")

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling, clion

I'm using CLion to do cross compilation (to armhf) on virtual machine (Linux Debian).
Packages were added through

```
CC_GetFile: Downloading 'liba52-0.7.4_0.7.4-20_armhf.deb' to '/home/debian/cc_armhf/cross_compile/apt' [http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/a52dec/liba52-0.7.4_0.7.4-20_armhf.deb]
CMD: wget --backups=1 -P "/home/debian/cc_armhf/cross_compile/apt" -q "http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/a52dec/liba52-0.7.4_0.7.4-20_armhf.deb"

Extracting'/home/debian/cc_armhf/cross_compile/apt/liba52-0.7.4_0.7.4-20_armhf.deb' to '$CC_DIR_TARGET_ROOT'
CMD: dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile /home/debian/cc_armhf/cross_compile/apt/liba52-0.7.4_0.7.4-20_armhf.deb | tar -x --keep-directory-symlink -C /home/debian/cc_armhf/cross_compile/arm-toolchain
```

I'm trying to compile it on VM, instead of on actual hardware, as compiling on hardware takes 1-2h.

Ask me if any more logs from set(CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE TRUE) are needed.

Here is toolchain.cmake

```
set(CC_ARCH_NAME arm)
set(CC_COMPILER_STRING ${CC_ARCH_NAME}-linux-gnueabihf)
set(CC_COMPILER_ROOT_PATH /home/debian/cc_armhf/arm-gcc-wrappers)
set(CC_SYSROOT_PATH /home/debian/cc_armhf/cross_compile/arm-toolchain)
set(CC_TARGET_PLATFORM ${CC_ARCH_NAME}-linux-gnueabihf)
set(CC_COMPILER_BIN_PREFIX_PATH ${CC_COMPILER_ROOT_PATH}/)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR ${CC_ARCH_NAME})

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${CC_COMPILER_BIN_PREFIX_PATH}${CC_COMPILER_STRING}-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CC_COMPILER_BIN_PREFIX_PATH}${CC_COMPILER_STRING}-g++)
set(CMAKE_LINKER ${CC_COMPILER_BIN_PREFIX_PATH}${CC_COMPILER_STRING}-ld)

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${CC_SYSROOT_PATH})

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CC_SYSROOT_PATH})
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)

set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE ${CC_ARCH_NAME})

set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} "$ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH}:${CC_SYSROOT_PATH}/usr/lib/${CC_TARGET_PLATFORM}/pkgconfig")
```

I'm using find_package from CMake as:

```
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
```

and it fails giving response:

```
Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_INCLUDE_DIR) (found suitable version
  "7.74.0")
```

so i tried:

```
find_package(CURL 7.74.0 REQUIRED)
```

with response:

```
Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_INCLUDE_DIR) (found suitable version
  "7.74.0", minimum required is "7.74.0")
```

Part of the debug from set(CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE TRUE)

```
CMake Debug Log at /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:241 (find_library):
  find_library(pkgcfg_lib_PC_CURL_curl) removed original suffix
  /home/debian/cc_armhf/cross_compile/arm-toolchain/usr/lib/X11/ from
  PATH_SUFFIXES while adding architecture paths for suffix '32'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:289 (_pkg_find_libs)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:595 (_pkg_recalculate)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:733 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindCURL.cmake:71 (pkg_check_modules)
  Libraries/L4T4B/cmake/L4T4B_functions.cmake:272 (find_package)
  Libraries/L4T4B/src/FileTransfer/CMakeLists.txt:8 (L4T4B_Link_libcurl)


CMake Debug Log at /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:241 (find_library):
  find_library called with the following settings:

    VAR: pkgcfg_lib_PC_CURL_curl
    NAMES: "curl"
    Documentation: Path to a library.
    Framework
      Only Search Frameworks: 0
      Search Frameworks Last: 0
      Search Frameworks First: 0
    AppBundle
      Only Search AppBundle: 0
      Search AppBundle Last: 0
      Search AppBundle First: 0
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_PATH: 0
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH: 0
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH: 1
    CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH: 1
```